# How to post data with C# in mono?

Tags: c#, url, post

1)

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("");
```

I can not use this method.
The  reason is my mono can not load the `System.Net.Configuration.WebRequsetModulesSection`.

2)

```
Navigate(bstrURL, &vFlags, &vTargetFrameName, &vPostData, &vHeaders);
```

I can not use this method.
The reason is can not use the namespace `using System.Windows.Forms;`

What else can I use to post data to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new KeyValuePair<string, string>[0]);
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("URL", content);
string responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(responseAsString);
```

Comment: I can not use the namespace using System.Net.Http; is it my mono problem?

Comment: @sunningshine I guess, as `HttpClient` should work. At least it does in Xamarin which is based on Mono. What version are you using?

Comment: Version = 4.0.0.0

Comment: some dlls are lost ,my mono has not some dll for examle System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: WinForms is not part of Mono, but HttpClient should work. Maybe you need to add a NuGet package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/)?

Comment: I add Microsoft.Net.Http worked .what package should I add if I  want the webclient work?

Comment: `WebClient` is part of the framework. Just using `System.Net` should do the trick...

Comment: But it is not work.the error message is "can not load the System.Net.Configuration.WebRequsetModulesSection"

Comment: I have no Mono installation at hand to check it, but either your installation is corrupt or Mono simply does not have that implemented -> stick with `HttpClient` if that one is working for you

Comment: thank you .another problem .I use your code ,but `await` is wrong ,because The `await' operator can only be used when its containing method is marked with the `async' modifier

Comment: You need to use async/await - if you are not familiar with that please look it up, as there is a lot of information available about that (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)...